# Finding STS providers for Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: identity, wif, foundation, sts-securitytokenservice

I've had a very brief look at Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) and it looks to me like I could say that my site is going to accept logins from other sites. e.g. anyone with a gmail or LiveID account will be able to post comments on a thread in my application. When the post comment button is clicked the user is redirected to a provider and they log in there, after which they are authorized on my site to post.

How can I find out who offers the STS mechanism and what the URL is to feed into WIF?

I've found the LiveID through a bit of googling but if I wanted to find the Facebook service, or Yahoo etc how do I go about it? Searching for STS providers and its various incantations isn't turning up too much.

Many thanks

The beta has been released fairly recently which includes a few STS providers for things like google and facebook for anyone that views this later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a hosted STS, your options are few.  You have Live, as you know, Ping Identity, and eventually the Azure ACS.  If you want to host an STS product somewhere, you have quite a few vendor options:

- Novell Access Manager
- Ping Identity PingFederate
- Symlabs Federated Identity Suite
- OpenSSO
- Vordel
- [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/)
- Redhat JBoss Identity (alpha)
- Oracle Identity Federation (I'm unclear on whether or not this product support WS-Trust, but I would be surprised if it didn't.)
- Safewhere*Identify

HTH!